# import socket.io using system.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, aurelia

I am trying to include to Aurelia framework project `sockets.io`.
I have installed sockets by:

```
jspm install npm:socket.io
```

then, I would like to import:

```
import {io} from "socket.io";
```

And the results is:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/socket.io-client@1.3.5/package.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Where is the problem?  Why is there a reference to `package.js` and not to `package.json` or `socket.io.js` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the client side (Aurelia), you should use the server.io client

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

var socket = io('http://localhost:9000');
socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
```

Comment: You can import this prettily easily using JSPM correct?  Is it the same package as listed above?

Comment: yes, you can keep that "jspm install npm:socket.io", because "socket.io-client" is a dependency of "socket.io"

Comment: I must add "jspm install npm:socket.io-client", because this module wasn't want to load. I think, the problem was with npm and jspm cleared cache, what I did yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is running socket-io then it will be serving up the client anyway. Thus, you should be able to add to the map section of your `config.js` file:

```
"socket.io" : "/socket.io/socket.io.js"
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently had issues loading 'socket.io-client' and found that

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
var socket = io();
```

wouldn't work as it attempts to load `socket_io_client.default` which is undefined.
Instead i had to use

```
import io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io();
```

Comment: import and then require??

Comment: @pungggi its valid in typescript.